# Excel cell value becomes DBNull when read with OLE

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ole

I have an excel sheet that I am reading in.
One of the columns contians names of departments, like "$.30 stuff".

Notice how the value starts with a **dollar sign**.
This is a problem as all those values are consistently read in as `DBNull`.

In my connection string I have set

```
...;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;
```

So from my understanding the `IMEX=1` should read values as text.

**When I change the name to pure text without special Excel characters, the code works.**

But is there a way to read in values with a leading dollar sign?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because it's a shot in the dark but can you escape the `$` with a `\$` with a `replace()`?

Comment: No that didn't help unfortunately. I removed the $ and formatted the entire column as "General" (no formatting), which is my "hack" for the time being.

Comment: Ah nuts. I've got nothing. Good luck! Sorry! ...Single quote `'`?

Comment: Looking since 20 minutes, and as always excel OLE is driving me crazy.

At least you can't use $ in sheetnames source ->[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/809a17c6-0ecc-4754-a64e-8afb01d78431/how-to-extracting-data-with-ssis-from-multi-excel-file-placed-in-a-folder-having-multiple-excel?forum=sqlintegrationservices). Would be awfull if it was the same for cells, but I think it's possible.